# Font size of Chapter and Chapter Title

Tags: latex

I am trying to make the title CHAPTER 1 is aligned in the center and the title of the chapter is aligned to the left.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\large\bfseries}{\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}  %controls vertical margins on title
```

But, then how can I change the font size? that is, for example, I need "CHAPTER 1" smaller than the title "Introduction".

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] that shows which documentclass and packages you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the font size by adding a command right before `#1`, like so:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\large\bfseries}{\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}  %controls vertical margins on title

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```