# quarto title font size is too large. How can I make it smaller?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto

Like the title says. Quarto title font size is too large. How can I make it smaller?

This is what I have in YAML

```
title: "Self-Statement"
format: 
  pdf: 
    fontsize: "10.5pt"
    keep-tex: true
geometry:
  - left=1in
  - right=1in
  - top=1in
  - bottom=1in
```

Comment: You might need to change some Latex settings, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58796041/5325862). Quarto has [examples](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/pdf-basics.html#latex-includes) on including Latex within your  yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [different font sizes](https://latex-tutorial.com/changing-font-size/) before the title.

```
---
title: \small Self-Statement
format: 
  pdf: 
    fontsize: "10.5pt"
    keep-tex: true
geometry:
  - left=1in
  - right=1in
  - top=1in
  - bottom=1in
---

## Quarto

Isn't it awesome?
```

---

[image: small font size for title]